# why is my Angular service (that includes httpClient) in constructer is breaking the module?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular2-routing

So basically I made a backend RESTful API and im trying to access it.

Thus I made a database-connection.service to do a post.

I am having problems implementing it.

The following is my code. If the problem is found and explained it would be appreciated...

```
+ app
|- app-routing.module.ts
|- app.component.css
|- app.component.html
|- app.component.spec.ts
|- app.component.ts
|- app.module.ts
|-+ homepage
  |- homepage-routing.module.ts
  |- homepage.module.ts
  |-+ spelling-app
    |- database-connection.service.ts
    |- database-connection.service.spec.ts
    |- spelling-app.module.ts
    |- user.model.ts
    |-+ intro-page
      |- intro-page.component.ts
      |- intro-page.component.css
      |- intro-page.component.html
      |- intro-page.component.spec.ts
```

spelling-app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { SpellingAppRoutingModule } from './spelling-app-routing.module';
import { IntroPageComponent } from './intro-page/intro-page.component';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SpellingAppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  declarations: [IntroPageComponent]
})
export class SpellingAppModule { }
```

database-connection.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { User } from './user.model';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DatabaseConnectionService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }


  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };

  public addUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>('http://localhost:8081/add-user', user, this.httpOptions)
  }

}
```

intro-page.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { User } from '../user.model';

import { DatabaseConnectionService } from '../database-connection.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-intro-page',
  templateUrl: './intro-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./intro-page.component.css']
})

export class IntroPageComponent implements OnInit {

  public results:any;
  private user = new User();

  constructor(
    private DatabaseConnectionService: DatabaseConnectionService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  callpost() {
    this.results = this.DatabaseConnectionService.addUser(this.user);
  }

}
```

Comment: It would be much easier if you explained what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "providers" to your module of the service. Make sure your angular is updated so that providers are accepted.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ...
  ],
  declarations: [...],
  providers:[DatabaseConnectionService]
})
```

Or use an Injectable in your service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root', //or providerIn:YourModule
})
```

You will also need to add the HttpClientModule in the app.module.ts not in the other module.

Also the Observable needs to be followed by an operation;

```
this.results.toPromise().then(...).catch(...)
```

Comment: I'm going to try this solution now

Comment: This was part of the problem. Yes, the HttpClientModule needs to be in the main.module.ts (app.module.ts). Also needed to update angular and add on `this.results`, to  `this.results.toPromsetoPromise()`. I'm gonna edit your Answer for completeness